# Rewrite rule .htaccess from blog.domain.com/anypath to www.domain.com/blog/anypath

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to write a rule in my .htaccess file so that any visitors from blog.domain.com/anypath are redirected to www.domain.com/blog/anypath

The rule that I've written below only seem to redirect blog.domain.com to domain.com/blog but doesn't seem to redirect correctly if the URL contains a path such as blog.domain.com/path

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.* [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.domain.com/blog [L]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have not captured the path with a `()` capture group to rewrite via the variable `$1`.  You will need to append that to your redirection URL.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.* [NC]
# Capture the full path into $1 and append it to the output URL
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/blog/$1 [L,R=301]
```

If this is to be a permanent redirection, you should use `R=301` in `[L,R=301]`

As always, consult [the mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for full details, and use [this clever rewrite tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) for experimentation.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to capture your `REQUEST_URI` and pass it onto the path.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will capture the path from the blog's subdomain, and redirect it to the correct URL.

For example, `blog.domain.com/post/736/test` will redirect to `www.domain.com/blog/post/736/test`.